# Photoshop CS6 won't start - "D3DKMTSetVidPnSourceOwner1 could not be located"

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I try to open photoshop.exe this notice appears:

`the procedure entry point D3DKMTSetVidPnSourceOwner1 could not be located in the dynamic link library GDI32.dll`

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [extensive research](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=photoshop+cs6+entry+point+not+found+gdi32.dll), this seems to be a common issue with corrupt files.
The consensus is to uninstall/reinstall Photoshop.

Comment: @McDonald's Yes, hopefully.